# Having trouble creating dynamic SKU's on liquid code in shopify

Tags: dynamic, shopify, product, liquid, sku

Hi im having trouble trying to make an img src change number(sku) dynamically based on which product i have selected. - its a bit difficult when i dont have access to the base HTML and only liquid code and templates.

(see screenshot 1)
[image: The codestring that needs to be with dynamic SKU]

I need help with creating a codestring that makes the SKU=(number) dynamic - so that it changes the SKU based on what product i have selected on the website.

So that if i select product A it becomes sku=productA

and if i select product B it becomes sku=productB

I hope someone can help.

Kind Regards Alexander

I tried putting in all the SKU's with , in between. and that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the product page you should be able to use {{ current_variant.sku }} to dynamically show the SKU in the src.